# Mostrar cantidad de archivos cargados a un input file que está display:none

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

Tengo un input file oculto por razones de diseño.

```html
<label for="file" style="background: green;">Diseño bonito</label>
<input id="file" type="file" style="display:none;" multiple>
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que a un lado de mi botón se aparezca el número de archivos cargados en ese input file. De manera que si cargo dos archivos entonces aparezca:

> Diseño bonito 2 archivos cargados

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es lanzar el evento clic del input[file] con el metodo `click()` al dar clic en el div del diseño bonito. Esto hara que se muestre la ventana de seleccion de archivos. Luego debes de asignarle el evento `change(fn)` al `input[file]` que se ejecuta cuando el usuario selecciono los archivos de su directorio.

El elemento `input[file]` tiene una propiedad `files` con la cual puedes obtener el total de elementos seleccionados con la propiedad `.length` y asi mostrar cuando archivos el usuario selecciono en el diseño bonito:

```js
 $("#file").change(function(){
    $("#seleccionar-archivos").text("Diseño bonito " + this.files.length + " archivos cargados");
 });
 
$("#seleccionar-archivos").click(function(){
  $("#files").click();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="file" id="seleccionar-archivos" style="background: green;color:white">Diseño bonito</label>

<input id="file" type="file" style="display:none;" multiple>
```